# Convert object to a datetime

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, dataframe, series

all,

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
         carry_dt product_type
0      2018-05-17         Swap
1      2018-05-17         Swap
2      2018-05-17         Swap
3      2018-05-17         Swap
4      2018-05-17         Swap
5      2018-05-17     Physical

carry_dt        object
product_type    object
dtype: object
```

I am trying to select the data frame by date:

```
allHoldings.loc[allHoldings['carry_dt']=='2018-05-17']
```

I get an empty dataframe why is it the case?

Do i need to convert the column `'carry_dt'` to  a date?

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: I cannot reproduce. What do you see when you print `df['carry_dt'].iloc[0]`? There may be unwanted leading whitespace. You are correct that converting to `datetime` is recommended as this increases efficiency and would avoid the issue you are facing.

Comment: thanks jpp when i do `allHoldings['carry_dt'].iloc[0]` i get `datetime.date(2018, 5, 17)` it seems that it is a datetime even though `dtypes`  says otherwise

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your column is `dtype=object` because it consists of `datetime` data as well as data with one or more other dtypes.

You should convert your entire column to `datetime`:

```
allHoldings['carry_dt'] = pd.to_datetime(allHoldings['carry_dt'], errors='coerce')
```

Note that elements which cannot be converted will be converted to `NaT` ("Not a Time"). If wish to fill these with some default date, you can do so using `pd.Series.fillna`. For example:

```
allHoldings['carry_dt'] = allHoldings['carry_dt'].fillna(pd.to_datetime('today'))
```

Then perform the comparison using `datetime`:

```
allHoldings.loc[allHoldings['carry_dt']==pd.to_datetime('2018-05-17')]
```

The advantages are multifold:

1. You will see performance and memory improvements as `datetime` series are stored in a numeric underlying format.
2. You do not meet with issues trying to align specific string formats.